# Empty Formal Arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def f():
    print (x)
def g():
    print (x)
    x = 1
x = 3
f()
x = 3
g()
```

I am learning functions now, why are empty arguments used in these functions ?

Comment: As you can see by executing your code, it raises an error, because when inside the function, in the scope of the function, x is not defined. Thus you should pass x as an argument.

Comment: @Mathieu, Yes I know aim of this code is exactly to show the error. But why we use no arguments sometimes like f(), g() when invoke a function ?

Comment: Because sometime you don't need an argument. For instance if a function just always return the same element, or if the argument is defined in the global scope and thus is accessible from within the function. It just depends on the application and the code structure.

Comment: A common example of functions without arguments are class method, for instance a class where a numpy array of data is defined as attribute could have a method raw.get_data(). It is also used for visualization methods: raw.plot(). (those 2 examples are taken from the RAW object of the MNE library for brain signal processing.)

Answer (score 2):

No arguments are being used (as none are being passed).

Inside `f`, `x` is a *free* variable. There is no local variable by that name, so its value is looked up in the next enclosing scope, which in this case is the global scope.

Inside `g`, `x` is a local variable (by virtue of a value being assigned to it), but it is not yet defined when you call `print(x)`. If you were to reverse the order of the assignment and the call to `print`, you would see `1` as the output, since the global variable by the same name is ignored.

Comment: What I mean is why don't we write def f(x): print(x) and invoke it like f(x)

Comment: You probably should. Whoever wrote that code didn't. While global variables are generally *frowned* upon, there are rare cases where it makes sense to use them.

Comment: So is there a difference between using an argument and not ?

Comment: Literally, yes. Whether the difference *matters* depends on the context, something lacking from your question.